# Print two different orders of an array

Tags: java, loops

I would like some support towards trying to print an array in its original order `n+1`, and its reverse order using a while loop `n-1`.

I have tried:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] testLoop = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    for(int i = 1; i < testLoop.length+1; i++) {
        while(i < testLoop.length-1) {
            i--;
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    }
```

However, I get an infinite loop.

I expect an output like:

```
1  10
2   9
3   8
4   7
5   6
6   5
7   4
8   3
9   2
10  1
```

Comment: What do you expect the inner while loop to do?

Comment: in the first turn of *for* in the *while* you have *i* valuing 1, then 0, then -1, then -2, ...,

Comment: it is not clear if you want to print the index (your code) or the values in the array, nor if you want to print a first serial in original order then the serial in reverse order or 2 values per line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nested `while` loop which does not check the minimal valid value of index `i` causes the "endless" loop.  However, "index" `i` is not used in the code to access the contents of `testLoop` array.

Printing the contents of `testLoop` in original and reverse orders should be as simple as:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < testLoop.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(testLoop[i] + "\t" + testLoop[testLoop.length - 1 - i]);
}
```

Comment: That some clean code! Thanks for sharing me the skill of indexing within the `print`. I can see that becoming very handy for me in the future!